# How to set the call back in web3.js?

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

I have two functions in a blockchain contract to get the investors and funds for an address and tried to save that in Excel.

**1st Function**  To get the list of investors:

```
getInvestorsList()
```

**2nd Function**  This will take the investor address as input and returns the investor's address and the funds saved for that address:

```
getInvestorsAndBalances(address investorAddress)
```

I was able to get the list of investors and the funds sponsored by them using the functions `getInvestorsList` and `getInvestorsAndBalances`.

The below snippet, which convert the data to Excel has to executed only when the function `getInvestorsAndBalances` executes completely for all investors. But this code is executed even before the call to the contract completes. Hence I am not getting the values from the blockchain to the below snippet.

How to make the below code wait for the successful completion of the function `getInvestorsAndBalances`?

```
dataSample = dataSample + "]";
console.log("dataSample: " + dataSample);
//var dataSample = [{"address": "abc","balance": "21.22"}]; 
const xls = new XlsExport(dataSample,  'Example WB');  
xls.exportToXLS('export.xls')
```

**Complete Code**

```
crowdSaleContractObj.getInvestorsList(function(error, result){
    if(!error)
        {    
            for (i=0; i < result.length; i++) {  
      
                crowdSaleContractObj.getInvestorsAndBalances(result[i],function(error, result1){
                console.log(i);
                
                if(!error)
                    {      
                        console.log(i + " - Address : " + result1[0]+ ",  Balance : " + result1[1]);
                        element = " {\"address\": " + result1[0] + ",balance:" + result1[1] + "},";
                        console.log("element: " + element);
                        dataSample = dataSample + element;
                    }
                else
                    console.error(error);
                });   
            }
            
            dataSample = dataSample + "]";
            console.log("dataSample: " + dataSample);
            //var dataSample = [{"address": "abc","balance": "21.22"}]; 
            const xls = new XlsExport(dataSample,  'Example WB');  
            xls.exportToXLS('export.xls')  
            
        }
    else
        console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: The above link answers are all related to Ajax. I do not need any Ajax related stuff.. This is pure jquery and web3

Comment: Yes, but the basic principle is the same: getInvestorsAndBalances is an asynchronous operation with a callback function, so you're going to have to use promises, combined with Promise.all

Comment: Could you please point me the exact example that I need to follow

Comment: Ajax stands for Asynchronous JavaScript. jQuery and Web3 are written in JavaScript, so you are, in fact, using Ajax, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version of your code that works:

```
crowdSaleContractObj.getInvestorsList(function(error, results) {
  if (!error) {
    const promises = results.map(function(result, i) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        crowdSaleContractObj.getInvestorsAndBalances(result[i], function(
          error,
          result1
        ) {
          console.log(i);

          if (!error) {
            console.log(
              i + " - Address : " + result1[0] + ",  Balance : " + result1[1]
            );
            resolve(result1);
          } else {
            console.error(error);
            reject(error);
          }
        });
      });
    });

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then(function(results1) {
        results1.forEach(r => {
          element = ' {"address": ' + r[0] + ",balance:" + r[1] + "},";
          console.log("element: " + element);
          dataSample = dataSample + element;
        });
        dataSample = dataSample + "]";
        console.log("dataSample: " + dataSample);
        //var dataSample = [{"address": "abc","balance": "21.22"}];
        const xls = new XlsExport(dataSample, "Example WB");
        xls.exportToXLS("export.xls");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  } else console.error(error);
});
```

1. Instead of a `for` loop, I'm using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the results into an array of [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which resolve with the value returned to the callback in `getInvestorsAndBalances`
2. In the next step, I'm calling [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) on this array of promises; this causes the code in the `then` method to be executed only after all the investors and balances have been retrieved asynchronously

**Improving the Code**

I've taken the liberty to refactor your code a bit to use modern language features and fix some mistakes:

```
crowdSaleContractObj.getInvestorsList((error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }
  const promises = results.map(
    (result, i) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        crowdSaleContractObj.getInvestorsAndBalances(
          result[i],
          (error, result1) => {
            if (error) {
              reject(error);
              return;
            }
            resolve(result1);
          }
        );
      })
  );

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(results1 => {
      const dataSample = `[${results1
        .map(r => `{"address": "${r[0]}", "balance": ${r[1]}}`)
        .join(", ")}]`;
      const xls = new XlsExport(dataSample, "Example WB");
      xls.exportToXLS("export.xls");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      return console.error(error);
    });
});
```

1. I'm using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of function declarations for more consise code
2. I'm using the [early return pattern](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/the-return-early-pattern/19364) (check if there's an error, then immediately return from the function) to avoid too much deep nesting of if/else statements
3. I'm declaring variable `dataSample` with [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const); you didn't declare it at all, neither `i` or `element`, which made them global variables – this is a bad practice
4. I'm using [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to construct the data string for XLS export
5. I've fixed formatting issues in your data string – it was not generating valid JSON because you got confused with the quotes and commas
6. I'm using *Array.map* to create the `dataSample` string, combined with [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to avoid the problem of having a trailing comma at the end of the data (which caused invalid JSON format)
7. I've removed the console statements, assuming you just used these for debugging